# \includemovie [autoplay] does not work in beamer

Tags: beamer, presentations, movie15

I'm trying to embed a video in my beamer presentation. 
The code involved is the following:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\includemovie[autostart,poster,text={\small(secondopezzo.mp4)}]{6cm}{6cm}{secondopezzo.mp4}
\end{figure}
```

When I open my PDF file, if I click on the slide with the movie, it starts with an external output . If I press f5 ( presentation mode), it does not start . The autostart or autoplay option doesn't work. Any suggestion?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can help us to help you by providing the code for a small document that shows your problem. Just edit your question and add the code. Please also state the pdf viewer you are using.